# Proof that a function is differentiable

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Let $f: B_{r}(c) \subset \mathbb{ R^{n} } \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a function, with $B_{r} (c)=\{x \in \mathbb{R^{n}} : ||x-c|| <r \}$, and suppose that $\exists \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} (c)$ for $(1 \leq i \leq n )$. Let $z_1, z_2 \in B_{r}(c) $ Proof that the function $\phi : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}; \phi (t) = f [(1-t)z_1 + tz_2]$ is differentiable.

First I don't know why $\phi$ should be differentiable on $[0,1]$ because the derivative of a function is defined on interior points of the domain. I know that it corresponds to the differentiability of single valued functions on $\mathbb{R}$ and thus we need to use the right and left limits as $t$ approaches to $1$ and $0$, respectively.

Second, I see that $\phi (t) =  f [(1-t)z_1 + tz_2] = f [z_1 + t(z_2 - z_1)] = (f \circ g) (t)$ where $g: [0,1] \subset \mathbb{R} \rightarrow B_r (c)$ is a path defined by  $g(t)= z_1 + t(z_2 - z_1)$ which is also a linear function and hence differentiable. $g'(t)=(z_2-z_1)$.

In order to proof that $\phi$ is differentiable, I need to show that $\forall t_0 \in [0,1]$,  $\exists D( \phi ) (t_0) \in L(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ such that
$ \text{lim}_{t \rightarrow t_0} \dfrac{|\phi(t) - \phi (t_0) - D( \phi ) (t_0) (t-t_0)|}{|t-t_0|}=0$

My bet is that $D( \phi ) (t_0) (t) = t \dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} (t_0)=t \dfrac{\partial (f\circ g)}{\partial t} (t_0)$ but I don't know what is the meaning of that. Is it correct to assume that $\dfrac{\partial (f\circ g)}{\partial t} (t_0)= \dfrac{d (f \circ g)}{dt} (t_0) = f'(g(t_0))g´(t_{0})=(z_2 - z_1)f'(g(t_0))? $

How can the existence of all partials of $f$ can help me solving this problem?

Comment: If you only know that the partial derivatives exist at the single point $c$, then $f$ may not even be continuous on the ball.